# RXJS How to Know When Finalize Completes?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, order-of-execution

I'm relatively new to RXJS so I apologize if this is a repeat. I tried searching for answers but wasn't able to find any, potentially because I don't know which search terms to use.

I'm trying to understand how I can know when the finalize block of a service call completes, because it updates a shared state variable.

Here is the stackblitz of it, though I'll also post snippets below: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xzvkjl

I have an Angular application with a service that sets a shared `isLoading` flag to true, kicks off an HTTP request, then uses `finalize` to set the `isLoading` flag back to false, so that regardless of success or error, the items that check the `isLoading` flag know that the HTTP request is no longer processing.

I've simplified that scenario into separate methods instead of separate classes:

```
isLoading = false;

public ngOnInit() {
  this.serviceCall().subscribe(
    next => {
      console.log("value of isLoading in next handler: " + this.isLoading);
    },
    err => {
      console.log("value of isLoading in error handler: " + this.isLoading);
    },
    () => {
      console.log("value of isLoading in complete handler: " + this.isLoading);
    }
  );
}

private serviceCall() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  return this.httpCall().pipe(
    tap(value => console.log(value)),
    finalize(() => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log("Value of isLoading in serviceCall finalize: " + this.isLoading);
    })
  );
}

private httpCall() {
  return new Observable(subscriber => {
    console.log("Starting emissions");
    subscriber.next(42);
    subscriber.next(100);
    subscriber.next(200);
    console.log("Completing emissions");
    subscriber.complete();
  });
}
```

I was surprised to find that the output of this example is

> Starting emissions
>
> 42
>
> value of isLoading in next handler: true
>
> 100
>
> value of isLoading in next handler: true
>
> 200
>
> value of isLoading in next handler: true
>
> Completing emissions
>
> value of isLoading in complete handler: true
>
> Value of isLoading in serviceCall finalize: false

Why is the `finalize` of the `serviceCall` invoked AFTER the complete handler of the `ngOnInit`'s subscribe block? And how am I supposed to know when the `serviceCall` has completed its manipulation of the shared variable if not through a completed handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### About `finalize`

This comes down to how `finalize` is implemented. I agree that maybe this isn't really intuitive. I'm part of a split faction that the believes the way it's implemented now **is** the intuitive way.

Consider an observable that is unsubscribed before it emits anything. I would expect finalize to still trigger, but I wouldn't expect a `complete` notification to be sent to my observer.

> *Six of one, half a dozen of the other*

Generally, the final thing that happens to a stream is that it is unsubscribed from. Finalize gets invoked when a stream is unsubscribed. This happens after a complete or error emission.

You can think of finalize as what happens during tear-down of an observable. Whereas an observer is observing the emissions of an observable that still exists.

---

#### Avoid side effects where possible

In general, side effects like setting global variables and checking them later in the same `pipeline` are considered code smells. If, instead, you lean a bit harder into the functional approach that RxJS streams advocate, issues like this should disappear.

---

#### Quick Aside:

Timing asynchronous events can often lead to strange or unexpected results (part of the reason you really shouldn't implement that kind of thing manually if you can help it).

Consider what happens when I add a delay into your stream:

```js
private serviceCall() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  return this.httpCall().pipe(
    tap(value => console.log(value)),
    finalize(() => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      console.log("Value of isLoading in serviceCall finalize: " + this.isLoading);
    }),
    delay(0)
  );
}
```

You would think a delay of 0 milliseconds should make no difference, but because every delay gets put on JS's microtask queue, you'll notice a marked difference in how your code runs. Before your subscribe gets called with the first value, `isLoading`  will already be false.

That's because everything before the delay is run synchronously and will complete before the microtask queue is run. Everything after `delay(0)` is run asynchronously and will complete the next time JS is ready to run the microtask queue.

---

#### Solution of Least Resistance

This isn't idiomatic RxJS, but it'll work the way you expect finalize to work in this case.

You can use the tap operator to catch a `complete` emission. Since tap will trigger on `complete`, this should fire before `subscribe` and therefore work for your use-case.

```js
function serviceCall() {
  const setIsLoading = bool => (_ = null) => this.isLoading = bool;
  
  return defer(() => {
    setIsLoading(true)();
    return this.httpCall().pipe(
      tap({
        next: console.log,
        error: setIsLoading(false),
        complete: setIsLoading(false)
      })
    );
  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the nature of finalize! However, with the solution you gave, I no longer get the benefit I used to of the finalize block, which is it updating the isLoading value for both successful and error situations. If I adapt your solution so that the pipe also includes a catchError with the same code that clears the flag and re-throws the error will I have a complete solution. It seems so messy though compared to finalize. I do want to address the code smell but for now I'm just focused on converting AngularJS to Angular w/o too many logic changes.

Comment: You can see errors in the tap operator too, for what it's worth (you can't handle them, but do that elsewhere if you're inclined). I've updated my solution to do just that for you.

Comment: Actually, one more quick update, you probably want to set  `this.isLoading = true` when `serviceCall()` is subscribed to rather than when it's called. Depending how how serviceCall() is composed later on, you may create your observable a long while before you subscribe to it (common with the `concat` operator, for example). `Defer` simply calls its factory function once subscribed, so it's a quick solution to that problem.